# Vary symbol rotation to point towards the next point in a sequence using Arcade and ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade, rotate

I have created a 3D map in ArcGIS Pro that shows the flight path of a drone. I want to use arrows for the symbology that point in the direction of the flight path. Each observation includes elapsed time in seconds. I would like each arrow to point towards the arrow with the next highest elapsed time (i.e. the arrow at 1.5 seconds points towards the arrow at 3.0 seconds etc.). I am not sure what type of expression in the expression builder would be appropriate to accomplish this using Arcade.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can vary a symbol in this way -- do your field attributes have a bearing? Or do you only have sequential records?

Comment: I only have sequential records unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Points to Line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm) tool to create a line representation of your points.  This will result in a new feature class with one record (line) connecting all of your points.

Use the [Split Line At Vertices](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm) tool to create a new feature class where each segment between each point is a separate record.

Then use basic symbology to [place an arrow at the end of each line](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/show-direction-of-route-with-arrow-symbol-in/td-p/613399).

Comment: Crafty, I like it!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I followed these steps, and one problem I'm having is that all of the arrow heads are pointing in the same direction rather than in the direction of the line.  Is there something else to check or try to remedy this?

Comment: Start a new question with some pictures of your problem and the settings you are using.